# Bundler Transformer Autoprefixer postprocess file knowing psysical path

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, autoprefixer

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC and I want to use Bundler Transformer Autoprefixer to process my css files.
My use case is a little bit unusual and I need to process css content from physical path like `"C:\somewhere\style.css".`
I think I can use AutoprefixCssPostProcessor class to do so, but it allows to process assets, that require virtual path to the file.
Is it possible to postprocess such file using AutoprefixCssPostProcessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works:

```
    var tempFileVirtualPath = $"/App_Data/Temp/{Guid.NewGuid()}.css"        
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(tempFileVirtualPath), initialCssContent);
    var autoprefixer = new AutoprefixCssPostProcessor();
    var content = autoprefixer.PostProcess(new Asset(tempFileVirtualPath)).Content;
    var absolutePath = "C:\somewhere\style.css";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(absolutePath, content);
```